# Removing white space from below Calendar

Tags: html, ionic-framework, calendar

How do I remove the white space under the NgCalendarModule as shown in the attachment?
I have already removed the events display from underneath the calendar by a blank white space is still appearing. Here are the image and the respective code:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a little late but I just solved this one:

I added this to my global.scss

```css
div.monthview-container{
  height: 275px !important;
}
```

Adding styling to the .page.scss was also causing me some trouble!